# how to post value to another page and get back the data without refresh?

Tags: php, ajax

I have many tags. I want click each tag, then post/get the tag's value to another page.

In another page, received the values and make a mysql query. Then return the resalt data to the first page(do not make an iframe).

I think jquery post and load may be can do that (but have no idea how to combine two functiton). Or maybe there have any other way. Thanks.

here is my code

products.php

```
<a href="data.php?get=hml03">model:hml03</a> 
<a href="data.php?get=hml04">model:hml04</a> 
<a href="data.php?get=hml05">model:hml05</a><!--post value from products.php-->
```

data.php

```
<div id="data">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,details,add_date,model FROM ctw_products WHERE (MATCH (name,details,model) AGAINST ('+$_GET['get']' IN BOOLEAN MODE) Order By add_date DESC LIMIT 20 "); // get value with a mysql query 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<div class="name">'.$row['name'].'</div>';
echo '<div class="model">'.$row['model'].'</div>'; 
echo '<div class="details">'.$row['details'].'</div>';// how to return this part of datas back to products.php 
}
?>
</div>
...<!--many other tags --> 
<div class="show_data"></div><!-- get the data back show in here without refresh the page.
```

Comment: learn jquery ajax with dataType=JSON..also read json_encode and json_decode

Answer (score 1):

First you need AJAX to be able to do this. The simplest way to achieve this is use a library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

You can either download the library and include it locally or link to it directly from the jQuery site. the following code should allow you fetch data from data.php without a page refresh

```
<!--include the jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_data(get){
$.get('data.php?get='+get, function(data) {
     $('.show_data').html(data);
});
}
</script>
```

Next, modify your links to call get_data onclick like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="get_data('hml03')">model:hml03</a>
```

Notice how we pass the id of the product to get_data, you need to do this for every link.

I would recommend you read up on Ajax and JQuery to really get the idea.